# Run-Time error '13' Type Mismatch when creating Dictionary from an Array

Tags: vba, excel, transpose, type-mismatch

Hi I'm trying to unpivot my excel sheet (transpose horizontal to vertical), and I keep getting a:

> Run-Time error '13' Type Mismatch

in my CreateDictionaryFromRowArrays function. Debugger shows that the error is here:

`For Idx = 1 To UBound(Keys)`:

```
Public Sub TransposeHorizontalToVertical()

Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngIdx As Variant, lngOutputLastRow As Variant, _
    lngDetailsIdx As Variant, lngTargetRow As Variant, lngTargetCol As Variant
Dim wksInput As Worksheet, wksOutput As Worksheet
Dim varDetailNames As Variant, varBrokersNames As Variant, _
    varDetails As Variant, varValues As Variant
Dim varDetailsKey As Variant, varValuesKey As Variant
Dim dicDetails As Scripting.Dictionary, dicValues As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim lCol As Long

'Set references up-front
Set wksInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("analysts_entl_export_Q2 Entitle")
Set wksOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
With wksOutput
    .Cells(1, 1) = "name"
    .Cells(1, 2) = "email"
    .Cells(1, 3) = "mapped"
    .Cells(1, 4) = "product"
    .Cells(1, 5) = "clientName"
End With
lngTargetRow = 2

'Identify the critical details and values on our Input worksheet
With wksInput
    lngLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    varDetailNames = .Range("A1:C1")
    varClientsNames = .Range("D1")
End With

'Loop through the rows, creating dicts then outputting results
For lngIdx = 2 To lngLastRow

    With wksInput

        lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        'Initialize the dictionary variables
        Set dicDetails = New Scripting.Dictionary
        Set dicValues = New Scripting.Dictionary

        'Grab the details and the months for this row
        varDetails = .Range(.Cells(lngIdx, 1), .Cells(lngIdx, 3))
        varValues = .Range(.Cells(lngIdx, 4), .Cells(lngIdx, lCol))

    End With

    'Create the detail dictionary and the value dictionary using
    'the custom function written below
    Set dicDetails = CreateDictionaryFromRowArrays(varDetailNames, varDetails)
    Set dicValues = CreateDictionaryFromRowArrays(varBrokersNames, varValues)

    With wksOutput

        'Loop through the Values dictionary to create output rows
        For Each varValuesKey In dicValues.Keys

            'Initialize the target column
            lngTargetCol = 1

            'Write the details to the output sheet
            For Each varDetailsKey In dicDetails.Keys
                .Cells(lngTargetRow, lngTargetCol) = dicDetails(varDetailsKey)
                lngTargetCol = lngTargetCol + 1
            Next varDetailsKey

            'Write the values (month) to the output sheet
            .Cells(lngTargetRow, lngTargetCol) = varValuesKey
            lngTargetCol = lngTargetCol + 1

            'Write the values (volume) to the output sheet
            .Cells(lngTargetRow, lngTargetCol) = dicValues(varValuesKey)

            'Increment the row counter
            lngTargetRow = lngTargetRow + 1

        Next varValuesKey

    End With

Next lngIdx


'Let the user know our script is complete!
MsgBox "Data de-pivot complete!"
End Sub

 Public Function CreateDictionaryFromRowArrays(Keys As Variant, _
                                          Items As Variant) _
                                          As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim Idx As Variant
Dim dic As Scripting.Dictionary
Set dic = New Scripting.Dictionary

Dim Results As Variant

For Idx = 1 To UBound(Keys)
    dic.Add Key:=Keys(1, Idx), Item:=Items(1, Idx)
Next Idx
Set CreateDictionaryFromRowArrays = dic
End Function
```

Comment: What's the value of `lCol`?

Comment: 'lcol' has a value of 4

Comment: So `varValues` is one cell. You are missing a dot in the assignment line for lcol which may or may not be the cause of your problem.

Comment: I added the dot to assignment line, and I still get the type mismatch error.

Comment: You never assign anything to `varBrokersNames` and if `lCol` is 4, `varValues` is a single value, not an array.

Comment: The error is definitely on that line?

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of ways to solve this problem. However, in your case, it throws an error because `Keys` is empty and you are trying to access it with `Keys(1, Idx)`. You need some type of defensive programming, checking whether the parameters are not empty before calling the function.

As a quick solution, showing you where exactly the error is, put this instead of your function:

```
Public Function CreateDictionaryFromRowArrays(Keys As Variant, _
                                                   Items As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim Idx As Variant
    Dim dic As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dic = New Scripting.Dictionary

    If IsEmpty(Keys) Then MsgBox "KEYS ARE EMPTY?"
    If IsEmpty(Items) Then MsgBox "ITEMS ARE EMPTY?"

    Dim Results As Variant

    For Idx = 1 To UBound(Keys)
        dic.Add Key:=Keys(1, Idx), Item:=Items(1, Idx)
    Next Idx
    Set CreateDictionaryFromRowArrays = dic

End Function
```

A probably not so "ugly" way to solve it would be this one:

```
If Not IsEmpty(varDetails) And Not IsEmpty(varDetailNames) Then
    Set dicDetails = CreateDictionaryFromRowArrays(varDetailNames, varDetails)
End If
If Not IsEmpty(varBrokersNames) And Not IsEmpty(varValues) Then
    Set dicValues = CreateDictionaryFromRowArrays(varBrokersNames, varValues)
End If
```

Comment: When I run this, Keys and Items are not empty.